# htaccess querystring to multiple paths

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, query-string

I've got a site with the following .htaccess rule:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?id=$1
</IfModule>
```

It works great but I need to expand it so that IF there is another path taken by the user, I can forward it (but the root path should still work).  I tried this, but the site just keeps processing the first RewriteRule:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?id=$1
RewriteRule /^(.*)$/^(.*)$ /$1.php?id=$2
</IfModule>
```

Any ideas?

So the root page could be

- domain.com/doug so this is /index.php?id=doug
- domain.com/dave so this is /index.php?id=dave

The inner path could be

- domain.com/group/object1 so this is /group.php?id=object1
- domain.com/group/object2 so this is /group.php?id=object2
- domain.com/admin/login so this is /admin.php?id=login

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I think you have to go about it differently.

The easy way would be to just pass everything to `index.php`, chop up the `$_GET['id']`, and `switch($id[0])` on the root folder ('admin', 'group', etc..) as a parameter in your script.

Perhaps even `include("group.php")` or `admin.php` inside the index.

Otherwise you're going to run into the problem of the root url's going to non-intended pages like: `doug.php` and `dave.php`

It can be done the current way you're headed, but you'll need to hard code cases for each root folder:

### Example:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/admin/(.*)$ /admin.php?id=$1 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^/group/(.*)$ /group.php?id=$1 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?id=$1
```

You'll need these above the working RewriteRule line. That line should always be last, since it's the catch-all / nothing-else-matched / default case.

If hard coding the root pages is not an option, (too dam many or always unknown), you'd be better off in the long run to have your `index.php` just handle everything anyway.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks stackoverflow for making my code sample look like crap

here's a better copy: http://pastebin.com/GeVTeBt1